# How do I define the entity for a relational schema in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net, text

I would like to add text on top of the rectangles to specify the entity names. How do I do this in draw.io? Not inside the elements but on top of them.Something like **Employee/Secretary** as shown in the picture below. [image]

Comment: Basically, I just want to add text above the rectangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put a text stencil (the 4th stencil in the "General" group) where you need the additional text. No need to paste from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a workaround if anybody ever stumbles across this topic. You basically write the word in a text editor and paste it in draw.io.